# Verify async function throws non-error object using jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Using the `jest` framework, how can I verify that my async function throws something *other* than an `Error`?

In my examples below, the first one works as expected, as the function being tested throws an `Error`. The second example, where the function throws a `string`, doesnt work - jest doesnt verify that the function throws.

```js
// Works as expected
test('verify error thrown', async () => {
    const expected = new Error('actual-error');
    const fn = async () => { throw expected; };
    await expect(fn()).rejects.toThrow(expected);
});

// Fails with: Received function did not throw
test('verify non-error thrown', async () => {
    const expected = 'non-error';
    const fn = async () => { throw expected; };
    await expect(fn()).rejects.toThrow(expected);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need 'rejects' in either case.  According to the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror) it's not clear if the `toThrow` method expects results to be derived from `Error`.  There is a regex form which might validate against a string.

[`rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects) says that it unwraps the rejection so it can be matched, and that might give you the error message string from `Error`, or a string if the result was a string.

Comment: Thanks for this, Dave. I was trying to hard to get this approach to work and didnt even consider other approaches. I added an answer showing the approach I managed to get working, if you're interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Dave's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72212562/6236042) was absolutely right; using `rejects.toThrow` was not the right way to go here.

Instead, I'm managed to verify the expected behaviour by simply catching the error and verifying it's value.

```js
test('verify non-error thrown', async () => {
    const expected = 'non-error';
    const fn = async () => { throw expected; };
    await fn().catch(error => expect(error).toStrictEqual(expected));
    expect.assertions(1);
});
```

Note that `expect.assertions(1)` is important here. Without this, if the code being tested was updated to *not* throw, the test would still pass.